# How can i fill the result of an sql query into a string variable in .net

Tags: c#, .net

i just want to get the result of an sql query into a string variable.how is it possible in c#
(.net) wihout using datatables.
query like this
Select Routine_name, Routine_Definition
From Information_Schema.Routines
Where Routine_Name = 'sp_sudh'

Comment: Post your SQL query code.  If you have not gotten that far read up about ADO.Net here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: yes it is possible. what is your query returning? Please add some more detail

Comment: If the query is returning multiple rows, what should the string show? Or, if it is returning binary data?

Comment: i have query,it's result contain text of a stored procedure,i need to get that text directly into a string variable

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple read example returning data as a string [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson04.aspx).  Without knowing how you are querying the DB (whether you use stored procedure or dynamic SQL, for example) it's hard to answer with much more precision.  The analogous ADO.Net Stored Procedure tutorial is [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx).